# How do I Install a custom ROM/recovery on a Galaxy Note 2?

Tags: cyanogenmod, recovery-mode, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I was trying to install CyanogenMod 12 Lollipop ROM on my Note 2. When I restart my phone in recovery mode, its giving me this screen:

[image]

After this I select the option "wipe data/factory reset" and then choose option "apply update from external storage" and when try to install, it gives me this error

> failed to verify whole-file signature. signature verification failed

[image]

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: I used CyanogenMod installer! It's so easy-to-use ![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKZPB.png)

Answer (score 3):

You are using the stock recovery, which only allows files signed by Samsung to be flashed. Flash a new recovery via Odin, such as CWM, TWRP or Philz.