# Update Samsung Galaxy Note 2 to Android Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, updates, samsung-galaxy-note-2

Is it possible to update further Samsung Galaxy Note 2 from Android 4.4.2 KitKat to Android 5.0 Lollipop?

Comment: If you're open to using custom ROMS: [How do I Install a custom ROM/recovery on a Galaxy Note 2?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/102883/16575) Samsung itself is unlikely to ship such an update (device too old).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but it involves installing a custom recovery (TWRP or CWM) and to download and install an AOSP-based ROM. Note that the following links refer to the N7000 model of the Note 2.

[Possible Recovery - TWRP](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1938733)

[Possible AOSP based ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-note-2/orig-development/rom-namelessrom-2-0-t2943424)